# How to find element using Id or Xpath inside a span tag Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I want to select this particular text "Password field is required." , which is apparently inside the `<span>` tag.

```
<span id="password" class>
::before
"Password field is required."
</span>
```

I tried to find the element using the `Id` but unfortunately it doesn't seem to work. My code is like this :

```
var emptyPassword = WebBrowser.Current.FindElement(By.Id("password"));
Assert.AreEqual("Password field is required.", emptyPassword);
```

I also tried using `Xpath` but still no luck. The `Xpath` look like this:

```
//*[@id="password"]
```

Can somebody explain to me why i can't locate the element using Id or xpath? thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the HTML you show and the code you show Selenium should be able to find your element. However, you are not asserting that its *text* is the value you want so perform the assertion like this:

```
Assert.AreEqual("Password field is required.", emptyPassword.Text);
```

Note the added `.Text` at the end, which gets the text of the element. What [`FindElement`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/dotnet/index.html) returns is a `WebElement` object, not a string.

Answer (score 0):

Do a text based search.

```
.//*[.='Password field is required.']
```

by . you are pointing to parent element here.